# Is there an updated way of accessing and listing installed programs from the Windows registry using python?

Tags: python, windows, registry

I need to be able to get certain info from installed programs (install date, name, path, etc) and im trying to use the winreg library but its not working, im trying to get it into a JSON object, and whenever i run my script it will run but not output the info i need.

```
import winreg
import wmi
r = wmi.Registry ()
result, names = r.EnumKey (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="Software"
)
for key in names:
    print(key)
```

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Please share a error message or something? Could be administrator token issues.

Comment: @JohnSmith it gives me a syntax error import _winreg
import wmi

r = wmi.Registry ()
result, names = r.EnumKey (
  hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
  sSubKeyName="Software"
)
for key in names:
  print key

Comment: Obviously, you are doing it wrong. You need to import wmi standalone. I am sure the WMI module is NOT part of Python.

Comment: @JohnSmith i did i used pip to install wmi, it still gave me syntax errors.

Comment: Frank, please post the code inside your question above.

Comment: @JohnSmith did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.7:

```
import winreg
import wmi
```

In older versions: 
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html

Comment: i already have that on the top of my code, i even isolated the script to see if any of my surrounding code was messing it up, it still doesnt give the output i need

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it, what was the issue? Missing read option.

Comment: I had left the underscore in before winreg on line 5, when winreg was updated last it got rid of the underscore, do you happen to know how to get more detailed information other than the name?

Comment: Yupp! In older versions.